# EXTJS 4.0 MVC load a view with chart whose store has inline data

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, charts, implementation, extjs4

I follow exactly as the MVC example. But I always get error in controller file. Any hint would be appreciated.

Here is my app.js

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({ enabled: true });
Ext.application({
    name: 'FSSP',   
    controllers: [Charts' /*,...*/],    
    autoCreateViewport: true
});
```

Here is my Controller code

```
Ext.define('FSSP.controller.Charts', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    // Stores to load
    stores: ['WeatherPoints'],   
    models: ['WeatherPoint'],

    // Views to load
    views: ['center.PieC'],

    init: function() {  
        console.log('charts controller init()');
    }   
});
```

Here is my store definition:

```
Ext.define('FSSP.store.WeatherPoints', {

extend: 'Ext.data.Store', 

model: 'WeatherPoint',

data: [
        { temperature: 58, date: new Date(2011, 1, 1, 8) },
        { temperature: 63, date: new Date(2011, 1, 1, 9) },
        { temperature: 73, date: new Date(2011, 1, 1, 10) },
        { temperature: 78, date: new Date(2011, 1, 1, 11) },
        { temperature: 81, date: new Date(2011, 1, 1, 12) }
      ]
})
```

Here is my view definition:

```
Ext.define('FSSP.view.center.PieC', {   
extend: 'Ext.chart.Chart',  

alias: 'widget.piec',   

requires:['Ext.chart.*'],

renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
width: 400,
height: 300,

store:  'WeatherPoints',

axes: [
        {
            title: 'Temperature',
            type: 'Numeric',
            position: 'left',
            fields: ['temperature'],
            minimum: 0,
            maximum: 100
        },
        {
            title: 'Time',
            type: 'Time',
            position: 'bottom',
            fields: ['date'],
            groupBy: 'hour',
            dateFormat: 'ga'
        }
    ],

theme: 'Green',


series: [
     {
         type: 'line',
         xField: 'date',
         yField: 'temperature'
     }
 ]
});
```

I always got following error:

```
The following classes are not declared even if their files have been loaded: 'FSSP.controller.Charts'. Please check the source code of their corresponding files for possible typos: 'app/controller/Charts.js'
```

http://mydomain.com/portal/ext-4.0/ext-debug.js
Line 8967

Comment: is Class FSSP.controller.Charts in app/controller/Charts.js ?

Comment: yes, it is. the controller class is under controller folder.

Comment: the error says that it can't find the FSSP.controller.Charts in Charts.js . use firebug network panel to see Charts.js 's source if it's define correct. or remove stores/models/views cfg from FSSP.controller.Charts to check if there are some error(such as path) to make ext compiler show the wrong error warning.

Comment: yes, the error says that the the file is loaded but the class is not defined. The file is loaded because it is listed in app.js as a controller. I list my controller code in the thread. I can't see any error within it. Even I remove all the view/model/init, the same error.

Comment: I had similar issue what I did is comment this line autoCreateViewport: true in app.js and move the Viewport.js code into the launch: function(){ .. }